# What is the value of GCLOUD_PROJECT while running Firebase emulators?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I run `firebase emulators:start` to test my functions locally.
In my functions I use the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable to initialize firebase-admin accordingly.
What is the value of GCLOUD_PROJECT while running the emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this pull request, GCLOUD_PROJECT should work like this:

> Manually tested:
>
> ```
> firebase emulators:exec --project foo 'env | grep GCLOUD' correctly outputs GCLOUD_PROJECT=foo
> firebase emulators:exec 'env | grep GCLOUD' gives nothing if firebase.json not present
> firebase emulators:exec 'env | grep GCLOUD' uses project id from firebase.json if available
> ```

Also, in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables), it states:

> There are environment variables that are automatically populated in
> the functions runtime and in locally emulated functions, including:
>
> process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT: Provides the Firebase project ID

If it doesn't work the way you expect, then I suggest filing an issue on the same repo.